# Babel не работает

Tags: webpack, babel

Вернее сказать работает как то странно. Настройки по документации webpack и babel. В webpack.config.js:

```
            {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
              }
            }
```

В babel.config.json:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

В итоговом коде после сборки я получаю его работу, он делает полифилы, меняет мне const на var и прочее, но смысл от всего этого если он оборачивает свой код в arrow function? Которые не поддерживаются в ie 11 допустим. Что за троллинг такой я не пойму.

Весь конфиг:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
const isProd = !isDev;

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts', 'index.js')
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: ''
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    isDev ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve('src', 'index.html'),
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].style.css',
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        minimize: isProd,
        minimizer: [
            new CssMinimizerPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
            }),
            new TerserPlugin()
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте опцию `targets`, например, `targets : {ie : "11"}`.

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ я уже так и сделал. Меня просто взбесил этот троллинг от них, зачем они вообще заморачиваются с этими var - ами если в arrow function все пихают... пусть это и их поведение по умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я помню по умолчанию babel делает издевательскую вещь - приводит код к es5 стандарту и оборачивает это все в анонимную функцию, которая является стандартом es6. Нужно указывать свойство target, и указать его можно в файле .babel*, в webpack.config.js в лоадерах или даже в package.json (по моему многие плагины оперируют свойством browserlist оттуда или даже отдельным файлом .browserlist, если я не ошибся в названиях)